# Returning polymorphic objects from Google Cloud endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I just tried to use polymorphism for entities for creating classes with hierarchy using objectify.  For example, I have a base Entity called `Animal` and have subclasses for this named `Mammal` and `Reptile` which is also entities.
And when I try to store the data and retrieve it, it works fine and I am able to convert from base `Animal` class to `Mammal` or `Reptile`.

But when I try to return a list of animals in Google Cloud endpoints this inheritance is not preserved. And I could not convert from `Animal` class to `Mammal` or `Reptile` on the client side.

Actually Google Cloud endpoint is creating another model type which is actually returned as JSON in the endpoints for which is different from our entities and inheritance is not preserved in those model classes.

Basically I need to query for all the animals and in client side based on the type of the object whether its `Mammal` or `Reptile` I will show the UI accordingly.

Here is a sample code.

I have two classes `Animal` and `Mammal`. And `Mammal` is a subclass of `Animal`.

```java
Animal annie = new Animal();
annie.name = "Annnnn";
ofy().save().entity(annie).now();

Mammal mam = new Mammal();
mam.name = "Mammmaaaal";
mam.longHair = true;
ofy().save().entity(mam).now();

// This will return the Cat
Animal fetched = ofy().load().type(Animal.class).id(mam.id).now();
return Animal;
```

I will return that animal object which might be a `Mammal` instance and I should convert this to `Mammal` or any other subclass of `Animal` based on its instance on the client side.

Does anyone have any solution or workaround for this problem?

Below is the JSON response for retrieving list of animals. But I was not able to convert the animal object to `Mammal` on the Android client side.

```json
{
 "items": [      
  {
   "id": "5631986051842048",
   "name": "mammm",
   "longHair": true,
   "kind": "animalApi#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "5697423099822080",
   "name": "Animalll",
   "kind": "animalApi#resourcesItem"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken":     "CjwSNmofc35tb3ZpZWFkZGljdC12Mi1kZWJ1Zy1jb2RlaGFyZHITCxIGQW5pbWFsGICAgIDruI8KDBgAIAA",
 "kind": "animalApi#resources",
 "etag": "\"cZTcM4l5N_SjrKcEhGkKJEl9rU4/rs8BjIS52gHgN0B1UGEEi2DERwE\""
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far with more specifics on the JSON?

Comment: @polarysekt : I updated the question with some code.

Comment: I'm trying to expand the thought process. So let me attempt to guess what you're trying to do. You want to access a derived class' member functionality with a base class pointer? [And the JSON text would help]

Comment: @polarysekt : Yeah i want to access the derived class member with base pointer but in the client side. Do you have any links which i can refer to ?

Comment: Can you post the JSON you're getting and what you're expecting?

Comment: @tx802 : I just added the json response which i am getting and i need to convert that mammal object from the parent type Animal to Mammal in the android client side

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately cloud endpoints don't use your actual classes when serializing/deserializing it's JSONs. It uses a generated "flat" POJO class which is completely unaware of any hierarchy you have in your original class. So by the time you get an "Animal" class on your Android client there i not relation whatsoever to the other classes.

Your only hope would be to send and additional parameter indicating the object's actual kind and assemble the corresponding instance manually on the Android size.

Comment: Is it possible to write custom deserializers for cloud endpoints ? does the cloud endpoint api allows us to customize the deserialization behaviour ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to customize that logic.

Comment: We do provide limited functionality for transformations. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations), specifically `@ApiResourceProperty` and `@ApiTransformer`.